# Mass payment and IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make mass payments, but I can not find the IPN unique_id in my payments.

```
[transaction_subject] =>
[txn_type] => send_money
[payment_date] => XXXXXXXXXX
[last_name] =>XXXXXXXX
[residence_country] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[payment_gross] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[mc_currency] => USD
[business] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[payment_type] => instant
[protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
[verify_sign] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
[payer_status] => verified
[payer_email] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[txn_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[receiver_email] =>XXXXXXXXXXX
[first_name] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[payer_id] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[receiver_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[payer_business_name] =>XXXXXXXXXX
[payment_status] => Completed
[mc_gross] => XXXXXXXXXXX
[charset]  => XXXXXXXXXXX
[notify_version]  => XXXXXXXXXXX
[ipn_track_id]  => XXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should receive another IPN apart from the above IPN which will have the content like below and that will include you unique id too:

```
[0] => txn_type=masspay
[1] => payment_gross_1=1.00
[2] => payment_date=11%3A50%3A03+Aug+24%2C+2015+PDT
[3] => last_name=XXX
[4] => mc_fee_1=0.02
[5] => masspay_txn_id_1=42507771L0091684X
[6] => receiver_email_1=XXXX
[7] => residence_country=US
[8] => verify_sign=XXXX
[9] => payer_status=verified
[10] => test_ipn=1
[11] => payer_email=XXXX
[12] => first_name=XXXX
[13] => payment_fee_1=0.02
[14] => payer_id=XXXXX
[15] => payer_business_name=XXXX
[16] => payment_status=Completed
[17] => status_1=Completed
[18] => mc_gross_1=1.00
[19] => charset=UTF-8
[20] => notify_version=3.8
[21] => mc_currency_1=USD
[22] => unique_id_1=ID001
[23] => ipn_track_id=86016e15b5f50
```